# I followed a tutorial to make a temperature conversion android app

Tags: android, weather

I followed everything step by step and after running the app, when I use the slider, my numbers don't change and stay stuck at "0.1". Did I miss a step?

```
    package com.example.tempconv;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.Locale;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView cel, fah;

    SeekBar seekBar;

    double c, f;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cel =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cel);
    fah =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fah);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(400);
    seekBar.setProgress(200);

    c = seekBar.getProgress() - 200;
    f = c * 1.8 +32;
    cel.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "0.1 C", c));
    fah.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "0.1 F", f));

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            c = i - 200;
            f = c * 1.8 +32;
            cel.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "0.1 C", c));
            fah.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "0.1 F", f));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

This is exactly what I've seen in the YouTube Video I watched. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong as it worked completely fine for the guy I watched.

Comment: if my answer helped solve your problem, please consider clicking the check mark to mark the answer as the accepted answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not letting the `String.format()` method do it's job - `String.format(locale, string, variable)`

You're hard-coding your string result with no where for your variable to be included.

For your double c and f, put %s in the string so the String.format can replace and format the string for you.

```
cel.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s C", c));
fah.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s F", f));
```

Note that this `setText()` is called twice in your provided code, and as such, will need to be changed for both parts (most importantly the `onProgressChanged part()`)

Comment: Downvoted. I hate "answers" being just blob of code. No! You did a change, then post the change only and explain what is it for. Otherwise your "answer" shows no educational purpose at all.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski you're absolutely right, I've made adjustments to my answer accordingly, thank you!

Comment: What exactly does the "%s" do? and thank you! @buradd

Comment: The %s is sort of like a wild card you put in the string which gets replaced by the variable you provide after the string in the String.format() method. You can do more than one like %1$s and %2$s, as long as you provide the additional variables after.  Make sure to mark it as the answer if it helps solve your question.